# Junit Toolbox WildcardPatternSuite with different Suffix?

Tags: maven, junit, junit-runner

I'm using Junit toolbox to run my unit and integration tests. It's working fine. Now, I have created another layer of tests that I would also like to run with junit toolbox but with a different suffix, not *IT or *Test.

```
@RunWith(WildcardPatternSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses("**/*BCT.class")
public class AllBCTTests {

}
```

But these tests are not running in my Maven build. What do I have to do to get these tests with a different suffix to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above piece of code works. Different suffixes can be used with WildcardPatternSuite.